# How do you move to the next or previous word in a Terminal in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I usually use Linux, no expert at all (very far from it) but I use it daily.

Sometimes I find myself using (someone else's) Mac and typing commands into a Terminal.

In Linux, I can use Ctrl+Left and Ctrl+Right to move backward or forward in the current line one word at a time (as in most text editors btw). If I try to do that in Mac OS, it switches workspaces, or brings to front another window, or some irritating thing like that. I think I tried both the Command and the Ctrl (proper) key.

Is there a different key combination for that in Mac OS? At the end I find myself holding down the arrow kay to move one character at a time, which in Mac OS for some reason is like 10 times slower than in Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Opt-B` moves one word backwards, `Opt-F` one word forward. These are `emacs` keybindings your  shell (`bash`) supports and has enabled by default. You need to have checked the *Use option as meta key* preference (pictured below).

---

Additionally, in your Terminal's profile settings, you can assign special escape sequences to e.g. `Opt-Left` and `Opt-Right` to make the familiar keyboard shortcuts work in Terminal, like these:

[image]

[image]

Use `\033[5D` to move left, and `\033[5C` to move right.

Comment: I found that with iTerm, it was easier to just add `"\e[1;9D": backward-word` and `"\e[1;9C": forward-word` to `~/.inputrc` (or whatever the `read` command shows for the keyboard shortcuts you want to use. I did this because using `option` as the meta key is not always preferable (e.g. German keyboard where the `~` maps to `option-n`).

Comment: You can use my profile: https://github.com/lingtalfi/mac-terminal-shortcuts , it has intuitive editing shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using iTerm, and want the Linux like Crtl + L / R mapping,
[slhck's](https://superuser.com/users/48078/slhck) suggestion works well.

Just add:

```
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
```

to `~/.inputrc` (create the file, if it does not exist), for Ctrl - left, and Ctrl - right, respectively.